# Adicionar classe CSS em Input ao Carregar a página

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quero adicionar `class="cpf_cnpj"` em um `input` com id `input-custom-field2` ao carregar a página, segue o html e o javascript que tentei usar mas sem sucesso:

```
<input type="text" name="custom_field[account][2]" value="" placeholder="CPF" id="input-custom-field2" class="form-control">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById("input-custom-field2").addClass('cpf_cnpj');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estava a misturar metodos de javascript nativo (`document.getElementById`) com metodos de jquery (`addClass`), por isso não fazia o esperado. Estes dois metodos retornam coisas diferentes. Faça assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#input-custom-field2").addClass('cpf_cnpj');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="custom_field[account][2]" value="" placeholder="CPF" id="input-custom-field2" class="form-control">
```

Para fazer com javascript nativo:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input-custom-field2");
input.className += " cpf_cnpj";
```

```html
<input type="text" name="custom_field[account][2]" value="" placeholder="CPF" id="input-custom-field2" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Tentei usar a mesma ideia fazendo isto mas não consegui, não adiciona a classe na label: [Veja aqui](http://codepen.io/wendell_chrys/pen/rLQyRQ).

Comment: @Wendell  aí é porque não está a importar o jquery: deve importar antes de usa-lo, assim por ex: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`, antes de todo o seu JS (javascript). De qualquer maneira tem outro exemplo em que não é preciso jquery

Comment: Eu utilizo o Opencart, ele já tem a biblioteca inclusa. Veja a [página aqui](http://mkgrafica.com.br/index.php?route=account/register), o campo é o `input CPF`

Comment: @Wendell a classe está a ser adicionada corretamente: https://postimg.org/image/jf871fc1n/ . Como pode ver aí, o elemento está com a classe

Comment: Sim eu vi e agradeço pela ajuda, só não consegui fazer o mesmo na `label` logo abaixo, onde quero exibir uma div dizendo que o campo é obrigatório.

Comment: @Wendell se é na label que quer a classe então selecione a label: `$('label[for="input-custom-field2"]').addClass('...')`

Answer (score 1):

Você pode resolver seu problema assim:

**Jquery**

```js
$(function(){
   $("#input-custom-field2").addClass('cpf_cnpj');
});
```

```css
.cpf_cnpj{border-color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="custom_field[account][2]" value="" placeholder="CPF" id="input-custom-field2" class="form-control">
```

**JavaScript**

```js
document.getElementById("input-custom-field2").className = 'cpf_cnpj';
```

```css
.cpf_cnpj{border-color:red;}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="custom_field[account][2]" value="" placeholder="CPF" id="input-custom-field2" class="form-control">
```